# Python: Iterating class properties?

Tags: python

I have tried using a dictionary to keep store/read values, but it seems cumbersome. So I thought I could just store them in the object itself. The values are simply byte location and read length. My problem comes from not understanding the best way to handle the read data per object.

The function mmaper does the work of reading the hard coded locations, splitting, then reading the actual byte data. It seems like there is a way to iterate through the different song._X properties, but that's where I get lost. I realize I will need to define each property under the class, but do I need a separate function for each property?

```
class song():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path=path
        self._tit='72,42'
        self._art='335,68'
        self._cart='115,4'
        self._date='412,6'
        self._freq='24,4'
        self._chan='22,2'
        self._xrate='28,4'
        self._intTag='20,2'

    def Title(inp):
        Title=inp

def mmaper(inp):
    with open(inp,'r+b') as f:
        mm=mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),0)
    start=int(song(inp)._tit.split(',')[0])
    read=int(song(inp)._tit.split(',')[1])
    mm.seek(start)
    song.Title=str(mm.read(read)).split("'")[1]
```

Comment: It looks like using a ``dict`` mapping to ``tuple``s would give you what you want out of the box. Why exactly do you feel a dictionary would be "cumbersome"?

Comment: "I have tried using a dictionary to keep store/read values, but it seems cumbersome" -- perhaps you can find a less cumbersome way to use a dictionary? If you want to iterate over them, they really belong a dictionary rather than hard-coded class properties. Also, why have the values be strings like `'72,42'` rather than tuples of ints like `(72,42)`? Split them and convert to ints at design time rather than runtime.

Comment: Yea I started with a dictionary using a for loop to get key : values, then read the data. It worked, but I changed when I couldn't use f"{}" formatting to enter the data back into the object under a corresponding name.

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree with the comments suggesting to use `dict` instead of a `class`, if you really want to stick with this approach here's what you can do:

```py
class DynamicClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self._attrs = {}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
             return super().__getattr__(name)
        except AttributeError:
             # You can change this behaviour if you want to actually fail if the attribute hasn't been set
             return self._attrs.get(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        try:
             super().__setattr__(name, value)
        except AttributeError:
             self._attrs[name] = value

class Song(DynamicClass):
    # You can add song-specific attributes/methods if you want to
    pass
```

Then you can:

```py
s = Song()
print(s.Title) # Prints nothing
s.Title = 'some title'
print(s.Title) # Prints 'some title'
```